# how to disable email confirmation when user creates an account in mvc asp identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to disable the email confirmation when a user creates an account in MVC asp.net identity 2.0

Comment: Did you do any research yet?

Comment: yes i did but didn't find any help

Comment: @Lucy Then you didn't try have difficulties reading or REALLY shouldn't be coding

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using ASP.Net MVC simply confirm it while you are registering it. If you are using ASP.Net Core consider Tom's answer.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser 
        { 
            UserName = model.Email, 
            Email = model.Email, 
            EmailConfirmed = true,
        };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 33):

Use the following when configuring aspnet identity in the startup

In ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
   config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
})
```

Aspnet identity will then not check the EmailConfirmed flag when validating credentials during sign-in.

Comment: Could something similar apply when using .AddMicrosoftAccount.AddAuthentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method instead of other cases, because in the future you may want to confirm the user's email by sending a link

```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        })
```